# Class exist in same file

Tags: php

php is a scripting language, so the class definition statement should exist after declare or use the class.

Why in php is possible declare and use class that is declared before at the same file ?

```
<?php 
var_dump(class_exists('TestClass'));#outputs true, why ? 
$obj = new TestClass();
$obj->hello();
var_dump('final');

class TestClass{
    function hello(){
        var_dump('hello');
    }
}
```

output is:

```
bool(true) string(5) "hello" string(5) "final"
```

Answer:
i created a example for understand hoisted in javascript and php, see in https://gist.github.com/AndresRicardoTorres/5815833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class definitions are hoisted, just like function definitions (unless they are in conditional statement blocks)

Comment: class and functions have the global scope, but my question is about order execution, why the class exist at beginning

Comment: Well, think about it like this: If I write `echo "Hello World!"; £*%)("$*%£$)(` then would the `Hello World!` be shown before the Parse Error? No, it would not. PHP processes the file in several passes, each doing something important.

Comment: where found documentation of hoisted ? why the manual does not mention ? and where found about php processes ?